# Moving a value to another object in JSON React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON file with days of the week and the opening and closing times of the store in seconds after midnight.

```
{
  "friday": [{ "type": "open", "value": 36000 }],
  "saturday": [
    { "type": "close", "value": 3600 },
    { "type": "open", "value": 36000 }
  ],
  "sunday": [
    { "type": "close", "value": 3600 },
    { "type": "open", "value": 43200 },
    { "type": "close", "value": 75600 }
  ]
}
```

On Fridays the store opens at 10am but it closes at 1am on Saturday. The value of the closing time is inside the "saturday" key, but I need to display with the friday key.
I can not modify the JSON file.

I have a map where I make a loops throw the days and another one to go throw the values of each day. So far I can display the values of each day. But I can not find a solution to display the value of the next day (when the store closes at 1am) with the corresponding day it should be, the one that has the opening hour.

```
      {days.map((day: string, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {eachDay.length && (
               eachDay.map((day: any, index: number) => (
                 <p key={index} className="hours">
                   {settingHours(day.value)}
                 </p>
              ))
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `index` parameter in your map function to display the closing time of the store corresponds to the day when it opens.

```
{days.map((day: string, index) => {
    const nextDayIndex = index === days.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
    const nextDay = days[nextDayIndex];

    return (
      <div key={index}>
        {eachDay.length &&
          eachDay.map((day: any, index: number) => (
            <p key={index} className="hours">
              {settingHours(day.value)}
            </p>
          ))}

        {nextDay && nextDay[0].type === "close" && (
          <p className="hours">
            Closing time: {settingHours(nextDay[0].value)} on {nextDayIndex}
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```